# Garage door stuck half opened

Tags: garage-door

When I open my garage door it opens about 2/3 of full opening. The workaround is to push open button again to trigger it to go up again, only then it fully opens. I have no experience with garage doors yet. Any recommendations I should look into?

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there are several possible causes of your problem.  Your best bet is to get a friend or neighbor who is reasonably "garage-door savvy", so they can look for the several common problems for garage doors.

Comment: If you pull the red cord to disconnect the door and the opener, how hard is it for you to open the door manually? If it is hard, your springs need replacing, which I would leave to the experts.

Comment: To add to what Jon said, unless the door can easily be manually lifted to about 4' off the ground and stay there when you let go, you may have a spring issue.

Comment: The door may need to be lubricated. But first disconnect the door from the opener by pulling the release cord and manipulate the door manually. If it is hard to move, then lubricate the door at the roller shafts.

Comment: Found the issue but not sure how to fix it. Pulled release cord and was easily able to move the door until certain point. I've noticed that when the door is opened at 2/3 of its height it starts to sink and bend in the middle which prevents it from opening. If I push on that bent spot from the bottom - it opens. Uploading pictures to original post. Is there a way to fix it or I need a new door?

Comment: Looking at the condition of the door I would recommend you get a professional as you have some serious problems.

Comment: You should put the information from your comments in the question, though.

Comment: Please use better software to do the image resizing, or just post the full-size originals. It's almost impossible to tell what's going on in these photos, between the small size and the *horrific* aliasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem was that one of the panels was bent in the middle. I used steel angle to reinforce it which solves the problem. [image]

[image: i7]

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept.